# MATLAB, Convert 4049 rows x 50 columns of spectrograph data into 3D plot

Tags: excel, matlab, plot, 3d, spectrogram

```
%Sampling Frequency
f=8000;

%Sampling Time
t=5;
%Data imported from microsoft Excel
matrix=Book2S1;

%Size Matrix
s=size(matrix);
h=s(1,1);
w=s(1,2);

%Set Up Rows and Columns
rows=(0:(f/2)/(h-1):f/2);
columns=(0:t/(w-1):t);

%plot
mesh(columns,rows,matrix);
xlabel('Time, s')
ylabel('Frequency, Hz')
zlabel('Power Spectral Density, V^2/Hz')`enter code here
```

This is the code that I type in to attempt to get a 3D plot. The goal is for me to obtain a plot that looks like the image listed below, but I continue getting a mesh error

Error using mesh (line 139)
Data inputs must be numeric, datetime, duration, categorical arrays or objects which can be converted to
double.

Error in Lab_3_1 (line 21)
mesh(columns,rows,matrix);

[What my plot is supposed to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLqZu.png)
The picture didn't want to get saved after being cropped, sorry people.

The following is a link to half of the data being used for this plot.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRMWfmFYDnwMSPzahD8k-aWAXHstbNRdlY4gmOHJoXkLaBb4PY7zF5-41yFkQHR4g0w3LrMFiz3ZqWJ/pubhtml

Comment: You should add example data or upload Book2S1 so we know what the format of your data is.

Comment: I only added half the data because the computer couldn't import the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try substituting your 4049x50 matrix replacing my random matrix f:

```
% t=5;
% fs = 8000;
lower = -60;
upper = 20;
f = (upper-lower).*rand(4049,50) + lower;
% s=size(f);
% h=s(1,1);
% w=s(1,2);
% rows=(0:(fs/2)/(h-1):fs/2);
% columns=(0:t/(w-1):t);
mesh(f);
colormap('jet');
colorbar;
xlabel('Time, s')
ylabel('Frequency, Hz')
zlabel('Power Spectral Density V^2/Hz')
ylim([0 4000])
zlim([-100 40])
```

Using the random data matrix f, I get this:

[image: 3D plot]

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the values that were imported into MATLAB were converted into string values. I stopped using the import button and used the xlsread function instead, and that allowed me to import the numerical values without them being converted into strings.

[Finished Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXpLI.png)

[Resulting 3D Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDZUI.png)

Thank you guys for the help and looking over the problem.